# apache 2 and php5

Tags: apache-2.2, php5

I have created a webserver with apache2 and it seems to run fine . I have also installed php5 on the server .To test if php is working , i have created a test.php with a phpinfo() function call and put this file in /var/www. whenever I point my browser to the php file location it asks me to download the file rather than running it . What's wrong here?

Comment: It would help if you included your Apache configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason PHP is not running. Make sure:

- You have restarted Apache after the install
- PHP is actually loaded into Apache (eg in Ubuntu you need also libapache2-mod-php5 and not just php5)

If both apply, please indeed post Apache config files.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to do:

1- You need to make sure that the appropriate php module is installed. Use; `dpkg -l | grep php` to list the php related packages.

2- You need to make sure you have a line similar to this in your apache configuration. This line enable the execution of PHP files under specific directory.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

3- You just need to reload/restart your apache server after applying the needed changes.

Comment: In most Debian systems adding these sort of lines is added by modules-enabled and modules-available directory which are handled by a2moden type commands.  Typically the administrator shouldn't have to modify apache2.conf directly as the `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5` will make all of these changes for them.

Comment: The OP did not specify the installation method and/or current configuration.